# How would you find the power balance in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, mesh-analysis

I have been having some problems trying to solve the mesh analysis of this circuit to calculate the power balance throughout the circuit. Here is the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBiojt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I was unable to solve the equations simultaneously, so I was wondering if I did something wrong? The mesh's go from left to right of the circuit with mesh 1 including the Solar Panel and the LED, and with the mesh 2 being a supermesh going around and excluding the current source. Here's the equations which I've got for the two meshes:

Mesh 1:

265.5 - 52(i1) - 0.33(i1) - 66(i1) + 66(i2) - 7.7 - 0.33(i1) = 0

to

118.66(i1) - 66(i2) = 257.8 -> [1]

SuperMesh (Mesh 2):

7.7 + 66(i1) - 66(i2) - 0.1(i2) - 0.82(i3) - 12.9 - 0.1(i2) = 0

to

66(i1) -66.2(i2) - 0.82(i3) = 5.2 -> [2]

And then including the current flowing through the current source:

i2 - i3 = 0.5 -> [3]

Comment: I tutor for this course at Queensland University of Technology. Nice try. Assignment is due at Midnight, best of luck!

Comment: I understand that haha, I'm not asking for the answer to this part of the assignment. All I'm asking is if my approach is correct or if I'm understanding this part incorrectly?

Comment: @DSWG If that is true, then this question reminds of a contest microchip or intel (or whatever it was) held where the participants would come here and ask the same question. Oh well.

Comment: @DSWG give him/her credit for a q that shows effort, unlike those questions that start “do this for me”...

Comment: Oh, @SolarMike and Dani, I'm not hating or anything. I'm just saying I'm a tutor and so I can't help :(

Comment: @DSWG sorry, didn’t mean it as low as that, but I was just pleased to see a “good” question for a change.

Comment: given the resistor ratios, it looks like you could acheive a huge simplification for an approximate answer by losing all but R1 and R4.